# QuickPdf - Memory leak

Tags: c#

I have a method containing code to create a pdf doc using the QuickPdf library.
Inside the method, I instantiate a QuickPdf object, create the pdf doc and save it to a file.

I then call this method for each file to be generated.

Now my problem is that the pdf docs' sizes are increasing with each call to the method even though the contents are basically the same . I am suspecting a memory leak but I cant see where exactly, since the QuickPdf object is being created and disposed each time on each call.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably easier ways of finding the leak, depending on your setup, but you might want to take a look at attaching windbg to the process and using it to investigate what is leaking. If it's managed memory that is being leaked you can use the SOS extensions to find out what is happening relatively easily, unmanaged stuff will take a little longer.

Take a look at this blog for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/tess/

In particular, take a look at her debugging labs. They are invaluable for anyone trying to debug anything even remotely complicated or memory related. They can be found here:

[Debugging tutorials/labs by Tess Ferrandez](https://web.archive.org/web/20151119050350/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are no "Dispose" or "Close" methods on the object that you need to call?

Alternative as a workaround, for each document, create a new AppDomain, Create the PDF and unload the AppDomain again.